# Android: AlertDialog.builder at Barcode Scanner appears twice

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I want to display the `AlertDialog` once I successfully scan and get the barcode data. Then when I click on `OK` button on `AlertDialog`, it will continue to scan the barcode again. All are working fine except the `AlertDialog`, the data is scanned and the `AlertDialog` is displayed as well but it displays twice of it. I only want to display one.

The working flow is first `createCameraSource()`, then scan a barcode and then display `AlertDialog` function named `dialogRack(String ..)`, then open camera again `openCameraAgain()` and scan a barcode and display the `AlertDialog`, function named `dialogItem(String ..)`. `AlertDialog` appears twice happen on after `openCameraAgain()` function

`createCameraSource()`

```
private void createCameraSource() {
    barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)
            .build();
    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                int width = surfaceView.getWidth();
                int height = surfaceView.getHeight();
                cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(ScanActivity.this, barcodeDetector)
                        .setRequestedPreviewSize(height, width)
                        .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                        .build();
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ScanActivity.this, new
                        String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION); //CAMERA_CAPTURE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder) {
            cameraSource.stop();
        }
    });

    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {
        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (barcodes.size() != 0 && !decoded) {
                decoded = true;
                try {
                    intentData = URLDecoder.decode(barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue, "UTF-8");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            cameraSource.stop();
                            barcodeDetector.release();
                            dialogRack(intentData);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } //End of if
        }
    });
} // End of createCameraSource function
```

`dialogRack(final String rackNumber)`

```
private void dialogRack(final String rackNumber) {
    Log.i("Alert Dialog", "Alert Dialog created for Rack Scanned");
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScanActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Rack")
            .setMessage("Rack Number : " + rackNumber)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    tvRack.setText(rackNumber);
                    openCameraAgain();
                }
            }).create().show();
}
```

`openCameraAgain()`

```
private void openCameraAgain(){
    Log.i("Camera Scan", "openCamera() start");
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() { }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            //Start scanning for item
            final SparseArray<Barcode> itemBarCode = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (itemBarCode.size() != 0) {
                try {
                    intentData = URLDecoder.decode(itemBarCode.valueAt(0).displayValue, "UTF-8");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            cameraSource.stop();
                            barcodeDetector.release();
                            Log.i("Camera Close", "Camera Source Stop, Barcode Detector Off");
                            dialogItem(intentData);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } //End of if
        }
    });
}
```

`dialogItem(final String itemNumber)`

```
private void dialogItem(final String itemNumber){
    Log.i("Alert Dialog", "Alert Dialog created for Item Scanned");
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScanActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Item")
            .setMessage("Scanned Item Number : " + itemNumber)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    try {
                        arrayListSerialNumber.add(itemNumber);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        openCameraAgain();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).create().show();
}
```

Comment: you need to dismiss the dialogRack dialog on ok button

Comment: @Bunny It is no working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved my issue using `static` for creating `AlertDialog`.

```
static AlertDialog dialog;
static AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
```

the display dialog function, create the dialog and show

```
private void dialogRack(final String rackNumber) {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScanActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Message")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   // onClick Function
                }
            });
    dialog = alertDialog.create();
    dialog.show();
} //end of dialogRack
```

and to ensure your `dialog` is dismiss after click, you could use the `if-else` statement as below,

```
if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()){
  //Action or wait for dismiss
}else{
  //Dialog is closed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AlertDialog twice because you need to dismiss the dialogItem dialog when you click on alertDialog ok button.Otherwise no of times you click on **ok** button you will get no of **AlertDialog**.

So on DialogItem on OK click

```
private void dialogItem(final String itemNumber){
    Log.i("Alert Dialog", "Alert Dialog created for Item Scanned");
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScanActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Item")
            .setMessage("Scanned Item Number : " + itemNumber)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    try {
  //CANCEL YOUR ALERT DIALOG HERE BEFORE OPENCAMERA 
                        arrayListSerialNumber.add(itemNumber);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        openCameraAgain();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).create().show();
```

}

Comment: did you cancel the dialog

Comment: what do you mean by cancel the dialog? Dont show the dialog ?